# Can you force YouTube embed to use HTTP only (not HTTPS)?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Can you embed a YouTube video using HTTP - so that all resources requested use HTTP requests instead of HTTPS requests?

I tried modifying the URL of the embed to start with `http://` instead of `https://` but both version result in HTTPS requests being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way Google would allow it's sites to use HTTP only. HTTPS is the default setting for Google's domains as mentioned in [Protecting data for the long term with forward secrecy](https://security.googleblog.com/2011/11/protecting-data-for-long-term-with.html?utm_source=wmx_blog&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=tls_en_post)

You should also use HTTPS, for your own security.